# Show that that the weak* limit of $\exp(inx)$ is $0$

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, weak-convergence

Let $f_n(x)=\exp(inx)$

I want to show that:

$\hbox{w-}\lim f_n=0$

If I got a correct definition of w-lim I should calculate is follows:

\begin{align*}
\hbox{w-}\lim\ f_n 
&=
\lim _{n\to+\infty}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \ f _n (x) \ a(x)\ dx 
\end{align*}

where $a(\cdot)$ is a fast decreasing function (means that $a(x)$ decreases faster then any Power of $x$?)

I am quite new to distributions.

Answer (score 2):

This is the [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma).